# Model Relations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I'm working on a new app in Rails 3 but I'm not sure how can I build the relations between the models.

Basically I have a `model User` and a `model Project`. An user can create a Project, becoming the project owner. But any other user besides the project owner can join this project as well, but as team member.

Would I need to create a new model for this team relationship? And how would be the relations among this all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing something similar with a photo gallery that has shared permissions.  Here is roughly the structure I've given it (though this is adapted from another project so may not be exactly right).

```
class User
  has_many :projects, :foreign_key => "owner_id"
  has_many :project_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
  has_many :shared_projects, :class_name => "Project", :through => :project_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class ProjectMembership
  belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :project_memberships
  has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :through => "project_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
end
```

Basically, this allows a project to have both an owner that's a user and a bunch of other members that are also users, and they can be accessed separately as such.  These are related using a `has_many :through` relationship, and we're basically giving a more meaningful name than what the default `has_many :users` would give us.

This also gives individual members the ability to join a project by creating a new `project_membership` object for said project, while still maintaining a single owner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How are the resources you are using on the routes?

Comment: devise_for :users and resources :projects, resources :project_memberships

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on associations (relationships).

There are a number of ways to set this up each with its own pros and cons.  Reading through the guide above should give you a pretty good understanding of the various options available.

You are probably going to end up with a many-to-many association (a project can have many users and a user can have many projects).  There you have two main choices: `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`.  The first is the most "automagic" but the latter offers more control.  The latter is my personal preference.

Like I said, read the rails guides so you know what your options are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link as well. Reading it I have to agree that `has_many :through` seens the best one. Still I have doubts: User model should have a `has_many :through` and a `has_many`, and Project a `belongs_to` right? Or am I making any mistake?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

So diagramming your model I would expect you have the following:

```
User --< UserProject >-- Project
```

This means a user can be associated with many projects and a project can be associated with many users with 1 owner.  Your tables would then have:

```
mysql> desc users;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc projects;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc user_projects;    
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id       | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| project_id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| project_owner | int(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Your models would then look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects
end

class UserProjects < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :projects
end

class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, :through => :user_projects
end
```

That should be enough to get your started

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This way I won't need the Project model to have an id field for the user that is owner of it? And how would be the resources, nested?
Thanks again.

Comment: @Luk  I'll leave you to research the resources as there is plenty of documentation and you can play with them in your app quite easily.  The project doesn't need the `owner_id` on it in this model.  Don't forget to accept your winning answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `Project` model will have both "belongs_to :user" (admin of the project) and "has_many :users" (participants). I have never tried it personally though. At the same time `User` model will be more complex.

Overall I think it makes more sense to make a "many-to-many" relationship between `User` and `Project` and "assign" roles to users (like admin,participant, etc) per project.