# How to make facebook like "Groups" in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a web application using Ruby on rails as my development framework. My application requires a group feature.

I am planning to have something like this. The user will have a profile in the app. The user can create a group. Now he can invite people to be in the group via email. Actually i am trying to make something like wikispace discussion forums. So the user/teacher will invite all students via email, and the students can subscribe to that group.

Now whenever the teacher posts something in the group, the students should get an email that a new post has been done, and they should be able to comment on the post and discuss the topics. I am not making any profile for the students.

Could you please suggest some methods, resources as to how to achieve this feature in ruby on rails?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You may want to head over to the chat rooms to see if someone can take you under their wing. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2):

in short you need to create different models and create relations between them - with the help of `has_many` (`belongs_to`) or `has_many_belongs_to_many` relations. I would advise you to create your "models map" first, so that you can understand relations between models better.

You can even do it on paper, that's what MVC is great for!

Try looking for references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144429/modeling-user-group-and-membership-database-tables) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784810/model-relations-in-ruby-on-rails).

Looks like you're planning to do something big. I would recommend you to start small - from little things like creating groups, users, blog-like functionality and slowly adding up more complex stuff.